# Multiple vlookups in the same cell, with their values coming from different drop down lists. How do I get a blank when one of the dropdowns isnt used?

Tags: excel, vlookup

Title pretty much says it all.

I have multiple dependent drop down lists (A2:H2)

Each time you select something, a corresponding number is entered into I2, with the numbers being separated by commas.

However, you MUST select a value from each drop down list or else you get #N/A error.

How can I make excel just "skip" or "ignore" missing values?

Thank you!

P.s.

I have already tried the IFERROR and IFNA commands but they do not work. I either get "TRUE" , with no numbers at all. And I also don't know how to make this work for about 6 different vlookups.

**UPD:**

```
=VLOOKUP(A8,'New Categories'!A$3:B19,2,FALSE) &", " &
 VLOOKUP(B8,'New Categories'!A$3:B206,2,FALSE) &", "&
 VLOOKUP(D8,'New Categories'!A$72:B$83,2,FALSE)&", "&
 VLOOKUP(E8,'New Categories'!$A$72:B$83,2,FALSE)&", "&
 VLOOKUP(F8,'New Categories'!$A$59:B$68,2,FALSE)&", "&
 VLOOKUP(G8,'New Categories'!$A$59:B$68,2,FALSE)&", "&
 VLOOKUP(H8,'New Categories'!$A$59:B$68,2,FALSE)
```

Comment: show us your current formula and what have you exactly tried.

Comment: `code =VLOOKUP(A8,'New Categories'!A$3:B19,2,FALSE)&", "&VLOOKUP(B8,'New Categories'!A$3:B206,2,FALSE)&", "&VLOOKUP(D8,'New Categories'!A$72:B$83,2,FALSE)&", "&VLOOKUP(E8,'New Categories'!$A$72:B$83,2,FALSE)&", "&VLOOKUP(F8,'New Categories'!$A$59:B$68,2,FALSE)&", "&VLOOKUP(G8,'New Categories'!$A$59:B$68,2,FALSE)&", "&VLOOKUP(H8,'New Categories'!$A$59:B$68,2,FALSE)
`

Comment: That is my code, and I would basically like Excel to simply skip the attribute if it is not selected from a drop down menu.

Comment: you can use `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(..) & ", " ,"") & IFERROR(VLOOKUP(..) & ", " ,"")...`. Let me know if it helps

Comment: Well, even upon trying it with just one value, I still get #N/A error.

`=VLOOKUP(A9,'New Categories'!A$3:B20,2,FALSE)=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A9,'New Categories'!A$3:B20,2,FALSE)),"",VLOOKUP(A9,'New Categories'!A$3:B20,2,FALSE))`

Comment: use `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A9,'New Categories'!A$3:B20,2,FALSE),"")`

Comment: Still not working :\ I get the #N/A error if A9 is blank, and if I select something from the drop down menu it just says "TRUE".

Comment: you CAN'T get N/A error if you're using formula I've gave you above! just type in cell `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A9,'New Categories'!A$3:B20,2,FALSE),"")` and thats all. NOT `=VLOOKUP(A9,'New Categories'!A$3:B20,2,FALSE)=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A9,'New Categories'!A$3:B20,2,FALSE),"")`, but `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A9,'New Categories'!A$3:B20,2,FALSE),"")`

Comment: Bloody hell, I am a doofus lol. Thank you very much man, it works like a charm. The reason I was putting =IFERROR at the end was because I saw many people using it that way on forums.

I just have one last question. In my current code, how can I make sure that Excel also ignores the comma of the number in the middle, if it wasn't selected? If I select nothing in B2, I'm left with this result: 20, , 79


`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A9,'New Categories'!A$3:B200,2,FALSE),"")&", "&IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B9,'New Categories'!A$3:B200,2,FALSE),"")&", "&IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D9,'New Categories'!A$3:B200,2,FALSE),"")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this one:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A8,'New Categories'!A$3:B19,2,FALSE), "") &
 IFERROR(", " & VLOOKUP(B8,'New Categories'!A$3:B206,2,FALSE), "") &
 IFERROR(", " & VLOOKUP(D8,'New Categories'!A$72:B$83,2,FALSE), "") &
 IFERROR(", " & VLOOKUP(E8,'New Categories'!$A$72:B$83,2,FALSE), "") &
 IFERROR(", " & VLOOKUP(F8,'New Categories'!$A$59:B$68,2,FALSE), "") &
 IFERROR(", " & VLOOKUP(G8,'New Categories'!$A$59:B$68,2,FALSE), "") &
 IFERROR(", " & VLOOKUP(H8,'New Categories'!$A$59:B$68,2,FALSE),"")
```